# Corrupt mysqldump tarball

Tags: zip, mysql-backup

I am using following script to create mysql backup and zip it. But the resultant .GZ file is always corrupt. When I try to extract I get this.

```
root@nix [/mysql_dumps/backup.16021]# tar -zxvf mysql-icme2193_icmedb-201309191523.gz
tar: This does not look like a tar archive
tar: Skipping to next header
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

What could be reason for corrupt file? hitting my head against wall since 5 hours.

Here is the code.

```
    #!/bin/sh
# System + MySQL backup script
# Full backup 
# This script is licensed under GNU GPL version 2.0 or above
# Modified from http://bash.cyberciti.biz/backup/wizard-ftp-script.php
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------
### System Setup ###
DIRS=""
BACKUP=/mysql_dumps/backup.$$
NOW=$(date +"%Y%m%d%H%M")
DAY=$(date +"%a")
### MySQL Setup ###
MUSER="root"
MPASS="****"
MHOST="localhost"
MYSQL="$(which mysql)"
MYSQLDUMP="$(which mysqldump)"
GZIP="$(which gzip)"
### FTP server Setup ###
FTPD="/mysql_dumps/direname"
FTPU="backupf"
FTPP="****"
FTPS="46.xxx.xxx.xxx"
FTP="$(which ftp)"
### Other stuff ###
EMAILID="notify@example.com"


### do not edit below this line unless you know what you are doing ###
### Start Backup for mysql system ###
[ ! -d $BACKUP ] && mkdir -p $BACKUP || :
# Get databases name
DBS="database_name"
FILE=$BACKUP/mysql-$DBS-$NOW.gz
$MYSQLDUMP --no-tablespaces --skip-lock-tables --add-drop-table -u $MUSER -h $MHOST -p$MPASS $DBS | $GZIP -9 > $FILE

### Dump backup using FTP ###
#Start FTP backup using ftp
$FTP -inv $FTPS << END_SCRIPT
user $FTPU $FTPP
cd $FTPD
mkdir $FTPD
mkdir $FTPD/$NOW
cd $FTPD/$NOW
lcd $BACKUP
mput *
quit
END_SCRIPT

## remove temporary backups from local server
 rm -fR $BACKUP/
### Find out if ftp backup failed or not ###
if [ "$?" == "0" ]; then 
 T=/tmp/backup.pass
 echo "Date: $(date)">$T
 echo "Hostname: $(hostname)" >>$T
 echo "mySQL database backup done. Transferred backup to remote FTP site: $FTPS" >>$T
 mail  -s "[mysql $(hostname)] BACKUP Succeeded" "$EMAILID" <$T
 rm -f $T 
else
 T=/tmp/backup.fail
 echo "Date: $(date)">$T
 echo "Hostname: $(hostname)" >>$T
 echo "Backup failed" >>$T
 mail  -s "BACKUP FAILED" "$EMAILID" <$T
 rm -f $T
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Your script clearly just gzips the file, it does not archive it into a tarball first. You either need to create a tarball, or just use gzip to "uncompress" the file.

Think of `tar` as like `zip` or `rar`, it simply puts all the data you pass it into a single archive file, much like a folder. gzip is what compresses it to make it smaller.

N.B: On the received file you should do:

```
root@nix [/mysql_dumps/backup.16021]# gzip -d mysql-icme2193_icmedb-201309191523.gz
```

Answer (score 0):

Your file have only extension .gz, so the tar its no necessary for extract it. 
Only use:

```
 gzip -d yourfile.gz
```

for use the tar your file would have tar.gz extension or tgz extension

look the link below:

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-compress-expand-gz-files/